# Laravel Authentication Middleware Auth::check() return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ldap, middleware

I try to implement ldap user authentication using the ldaprecord package with Laravel 8. Although user authentication is successful, I cannot access the session when I check it through the middleware.

After Auth::login($user), Auth::check() method returns true, somehow on Auth Middleware it return false. I use file for session_driver. The file is created at storage/framework/sessions successfully, so permissions look okay to me. What should I pay attention to for the session to be permanent?

**AuthController.php**

```
 class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        public function getLogin(){
            return view('login');
        }
    
        public function postLoginForm(Request $request){
            $request->validate([
                'username' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
    
            $username = $request->username . "@iegm.local";
            $connection = Container::getConnection('default');
    
            if ($connection->auth()->attempt($username, $request->password)) {
                $user = User::firstOrCreate(['username' => $request->username], [
                    'is_admin' => 0,
                    'is_active' => 1
                ]);
                Auth::login($user);
                dd(Auth::check()); // --> return true

                return redirect()->route('get.anasayfa');
            }
    
            return back()->with('fail', 'basarisiz');
        }
    
        public function logout() {
            Session::flush();
            Auth::logout();
    
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'ldap',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'ldap' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => App\Models\LdapUser::class,
        ],
    ],  
];
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
   
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ]
    ];

   
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'log' => \App\Http\Middleware\LogMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [AnasayfaController::class, 'index'])->name('get.anasayfa');
});
```

**Authenticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        dd(Auth::check()) // --> return false
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('get.login');
        }
    }
}
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public const HOME = '/home';

    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: does your browser set a correct cookie?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it does.

Comment: When you refresh the site after login, does the cookie stay? Can you try and set random values in the session and read it out? When you set a cookie or session value it will be available working during the same request process, like `Auth::login`, so you cant rely on that. Maybe try to use the default database login instead of ldap for testing purposes

Comment: can you edit the question and add your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file? There's something I need to see

Comment: @Alex I set random values in the session and i can read it when I refresh the page. I currently use database login on production but i need to use ldap login.

Comment: @EyadBereh I added `RouteServiceProvider.php` file to the question.

Comment: @Taha so maybe the ldap provider doesnt function correctly and its not laravel related. Any idea how to further debug?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but when I used two different models and edited the `auth.php` file as follows, the `Authenticaion` middleware worked as I expected.

**LdapUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use LdapRecord\Models\Model;

class LdapUser extends Model
{
    public static array $objectClasses = ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user'];
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'is_admin',
        'is_active'
    ];
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

**auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ]
],
```